# Combining heterogeneous data sets for more powerful machine learning

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, sentiment-analysis, multitask-learning

Suppose we have two data sets of movie reviews; one from IMDB and one from Rotten Tomatoes (RT). Each entry has a written-review and a score attached to it. The concatenated datasets might look like

**Movie**|**Score**|**Review**|**Site**

The Lion King|9.8|"This is one of the best movies ever!"|IMDB

The Lion King|4.5|"This move absolutely made my childhood"|RT

etc.

Our task is to predict scores from reviews. This is similar to the Kaggle IMDB sentiment analysis challenge, except we're trying to predict a continuous variable from two data sources. For a single data set, we might train a model in Keras with an embedding and lstm layer. In R:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
   layer_embedding(input_dim = features, output_dim = 32) %>%
   layer_lstm(units = 32) %>%
   layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "linear")
```

where features is the number of words in our corpus.

**How do we combine the IMDB and Rotten Tomatoes data sets to maximize our predictions?**

My first thought is to include the site column as a categorical variable and then let the model learn how to best combine them. Would this cause a skew in the predictions?

We could also try multi-task learning, but most of these methods seem to be designed to predict repeated observations. Such as 5 different people reviewing the same 100 movies.

Some things to consider:

1. IMDB and RT don't have all the same movies (i.e. not a repeated observation problem)
2. There are words local to each dataset. i.e. the word "rotten" might be a frequent word on RT, but never appears in the IMDB dataset.
3. The outcome measures are different. RT uses a 5 star scale, whereas IMDB uses a 10 star one.

How do we deal with this heterogeneity?

Answer (score 1):

Following your considerations:

> IMDB and RT don't have all the same movies

I would build a larger dataset of movies, aggregate all observations available, and run a model on that.

---

> There are words local to each dataset. i.e. the word "rotten" might be
>   a frequent word on RT, but never appears in the IMDB dataset.

I think this doesn't constitute a problem once you aggregate data in a larger dataset. At that point you can run some NLP method on the whole aggregated corpus. Let me know what you think.

---

> The outcome measures are different. RT uses a 5 star scale, whereas
>   IMDB uses a 10 star one. How do we deal with this heterogeneity?

You just need to uniform the scales on a given interval like [0, 1]. Then all votes could be compared.

Comment: Aggregating the datasets does seem like the simplest solution. Could we improve accuracy by training two separate models and letting them share information for certain layers? Something like cross-stitch networks? The movie example I provided is a simple case, but I'm more interested in the general question of combining heterogenous datasets that have a similar underlying structure, but also require their own fine tuning.

Comment: I don't know if training two separate models would provide better results (it could be), but it would certainly be much more complicated and time consuming. Personally, I am all for aggregation, that would make your life easier and will let two separate pieces of information to complete/enhance each other. For example, NLP techniques could find associations between words that two separate models could never capture.